# Не запускается таймер

Tags: javascript

Почему не запускается таймер? http://jsfiddle.net/pL5dxkkg/

Если запустить его из скрипта, добавив в самый конец кода строчку myTime(); то всё работает, а с кнопки не стартует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас функция myTime определена внутри window.onload. Она не видна снаружи.

http://jsfiddle.net/pL5dxkkg/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<input type="button" value="start" id="myTimeStart" />
```

JS:

```
i=60;
var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
function myTime() {
i = i-1;
timer.innerHTML=i;
var timerId = setTimeout(myTime, 100);
    if (i<=10) {timer.style.color='red';}
    if (i<=0) {clearTimeout(timerId);}
}
document.getElementById('myTimeStart').onclick = myTime;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.